# Wicket replacing items in ListView

Tags: java, listview, wicket

I want to change the data of a listview on a Button Click.

This is what I do currently:

```
final PageableListView<Users> listview = new PageableListView<Users>("rows", displayList, 10) {
    //....
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Users> item) {
        item.add(new Label("username").setOutputMarkupId(true));
        // .. other fields
    }
}

final IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink<MyPanel> sublist = new IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink<MyPanel>("sublist") {
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                displayList = // get new list
                listview.setList(displayList);
                target.addChildren(listview, Label.class);
        }
};
add(sublist);
```

This works if the new list is exactly the same size as the old list. In any other case I get an

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'd add the whole list to the target e.g. `target.add(listview);`. there are some know ajax IE issues when updating partial lists.

Comment: I tried that already, but listviews can't be replaced (as far as I can tell): `This component is a repeater and cannot be repainted via ajax directly. Instead add its parent or another markup container higher in the hierarchy.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since I can't update the listview via `target.add(listview);` I added a `WebMarkupContainer` like this:

```
final WebMarkupContainer datacontainer = new WebMarkupContainer("data");
datacontainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(datacontainer);
```

and now I can update the `onClick` method:

```
target.add(datacontainer);
```

this works fine - problem solved.

but why replacing the children didn't work is still unclear to me

Comment: with #addChildren() your adding all Labels to the AjaxRequestTarget. Note that ListItems get their model via index from the parental repeater. The ListItem without matching item in the list will throw and IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: The children of the listview are already rendered from the previous list, adding them to the target won't help creating new ones.